# After preventing the default behavior the enter key seems to be refreshing the global variables in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, enter

I am writing a search function much like the [cmd+f] function in a browser. I have everything working but I want the enter key on press to cycle through the results through the page. I also have arrow buttons that call the function I wrote and they work. I prevented the default behavior of enter using:

```
$('form').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I am using this code to call the function on enter:

```
$('form').keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        nextSearch();
    }
});
```

It works for the first result but I think it resets the global variable I use to mark the place. The only logical answer I can think of is that pressing enter now refreshes the JavaScript. Is there a way to prevent this?

I use these global variables to keep track:

```
window.luCurrentNumber = 0;
window.luLastActive = 0;
```

Comment: You aren't stopping the `keyup` event with your `keydown` event binding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you corrected, you the arrow keys and the enter keys to tab instead of performing their default. Here is an example of a function that I use to treat the Enter key as a tab, which I wrote because users kept hitting the enter key and accidentally submitting the page.

```
    //Make enter key is pressed, tab instead of submitting.
    $('body').on('keydown', 'input, select', function (e) {
        var self = $(this)
              , form = self.parents('form:eq(0)')
              , focusable
              , next
              ;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            focusable = form.find('input,a,select,button').filter(':visible');
            next = focusable.eq(focusable.index(this) + 1);
            if (next.length) {
                next.focus();
            } else {
                form.submit();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Though it's not exactly what you are trying to do, I think it should set you on the right path.